# Portable way to get file size (in bytes) in the shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, solaris

On Linux, I use `stat --format="%s" FILE`, but the [Solaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_%28operating_system%29) machine I have access to doesn't have the `stat` command. What should I use then?

I'm writing Bash scripts and can't really install any new software on the system.

I've considered already using:

```
perl -e '@x=stat(shift);print $x[7]' FILE
```

or even:

```
ls -nl FILE | awk '{print $5}'
```

But neither of these looks sensible - running [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) just to get file size? Or running two programs to do the same?

Comment: well a bash script *is* software, and if you can put that on the system, you can install software.

Comment: Technically - true. I meant that I don't have root privileges, and can't install new packages. Sure installing in home dir is possible. But not really when I have to make the script that is portable, and installation on "X" machines, new additional packages becomes tricky.

Answer (score 242, accepted):

`wc -c < filename` (short for word count, `-c` prints the byte count) is a portable, [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/wc.html) solution. Only the output format might not be uniform across platforms as some spaces may be prepended (which is the case for Solaris).

Do not omit the input redirection. When the file is passed as an argument, the file name is printed after the byte count.

I was worried it wouldn't work for binary files, but it works OK on both Linux and Solaris. You can try it with `wc -c < /usr/bin/wc`. Moreover, POSIX utilities are [guaranteed to handle binary files](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403), unless specified otherwise explicitly.

Comment: Or just `wc -c < file` if you don't want the filename appearing.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, though, `wc` in a pipeline must `read()` the entire stream to count the bytes.  The `ls`/`awk` solutions (and similar) use a system call to get the size, which *should* be linear time (versus O(size))

Comment: I recall `wc` being very slow the last time I did that on a full hard disk. It was slow enough that I could re-write the script before the first one finished, came here to remember how I did it lol.

Comment: I wouldn't use `wc -c`; it looks much neater but `ls` + `awk` is better for speed/resource use. Also, I just wanted to point out that you actually need to post-process the results of `wc` as well because on some systems it will have whitespace before the result, which you may need to strip before you can do comparisons.

Comment: What would be then the best option to print the result in human friendly format? e.g. MB, KB

Comment: `wc -c` is great, but it will not work if you don't have read access to the file.

Comment: The `stat` and `ls` utilities just execut the `lstat` syscall and get the file length without reading the file. Thus, they do not need the read permission and their performance does not depend on the file's length. `wc` actually opens the file and usually reads it, making it perform much worse on large files. But [GNU coreutils wc](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/wc.c) optimizes when only byte count of a regular file is wanted: it uses `fstat` and `lseek` syscalls to get the count. See the comment with `(dd ibs=99k skip=1 count=0; ./wc -c) < /etc/group` in its source.

Comment: Would it be efficient to use `wc -c < FILE` for very large files such as 100GB ? @Carl Smotricz

Comment: @alper: I haven't tested, but I suspect that redirecting a large file like this is terribly slow. My answer was about measuring file size portably, not efficiently. For a quick size based on the directory data, you'd probably be better off looking at some of the other answers here.

Answer (score 51):

I ended up writing my own program (really small) to display just the size. More information is in *[bfsize - print file size in bytes (and just that)](http://fwhacking.blogspot.com/2011/03/bfsize-print-file-size-in-bytes-and.html)*.

The two cleanest ways in my opinion with common Linux tools are:

```
stat -c %s /usr/bin/stat

50000


wc -c < /usr/bin/wc

36912
```

But I just don't want to be typing parameters or pipe the output just to get a file size, so I'm using my own *bfsize*.

Comment: First line of problem description states that stat is not an option, and the wc -c is the top answer for over a year now, so I'm not sure what is the point of this answer.

Comment: The point is in people like me who find this SO question in Google and `stat` _is_ an option for them.

Comment: I'm working on an embedded system where `wc -c` takes 4090 msec on a 10 MB file vs "0" msec for `stat -c %s`, so I agree it's helpful to have alternative solutions even when they don't answer the exact question posed.

Comment: "stat -c" is not portable / does not accept the same arguments on MacOS as it does on Linux.   "wc -c" will be very slow for large files.

Comment: `stat` gives the size of locked file, when `wc` does not - Cygwin under Windows on c:\pagefile.sys.

Comment: stat is not portable either. `stat -c %s /usr/bin/stat`
`stat: illegal option -- c`
`usage: stat [-FlLnqrsx] [-f format] [-t timefmt] [file ...]`

Comment: i did say that.  try my answer, based on **ls** should be quite portable http://stackoverflow.com/a/15522969/912236

Comment: I always wondered why the `stat` CLI utility was never included in POSIX.

Answer (score 39):

Even though [`du`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du_(Unix)) usually prints disk usage and not actual data size, the [GNU Core Utilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities) `du` can print a file's "apparent size" in bytes:

```
du -b FILE
```

But it won't work under [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution), [Solaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_%28operating_system%29), [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS), etc.

Comment: On MacOS X, `brew install coreutils` and `gdu -b` will achieve the same effect

Comment: I prefer this method because `wc` needs to read the whole file befor giving a result, `du` is immediate.

Comment: POSIX mentions `du -b` in a completely different context in [`du` rationale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/du.html#tag_20_36_18).

Comment: This uses just the `lstat` call, so its performance does not depend on file size. Shorter than `stat -c '%s'`, but less intuitive and works differently for folders (prints size of each file inside).

Comment: [FreeBSD `du`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=du&sektion=1) can get close using `du -A -B1`, but it still prints the result in multiples of 1024B blocks. Did not manage to get it to print bytes count. Even setting `BLOCKSIZE=1` in the environemnt does not help, because 512B block are used then.

Comment: Where *does* it work? Only on Linux?

Answer (score 13):

Finally I decided to use *ls*, and Bash array expansion:

```
TEMP=( $( ls -ln FILE ) )
SIZE=${TEMP[4]}
```

It's not really nice, but at least it does only one fork+execve, and it doesn't rely on a secondary programming language ([Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl), [Ruby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29), [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), or whatever).

Comment: Just an aside - the 'l' in '-ln' is not required; '-n' is exactly the same as '-ln'

Comment: No, it's not. Just compare outputs.

Comment: One would guess the portable `ls -ln FILE | { read _ _ _ _ size _ && echo "$size"; }` needs not fork for the second step of the pipeline, as it uses just built-ins, but Bash 4.2.37 on Linux forks twice (still only one `execve`, though).

Comment: `read _ _ _ _ size _ <<<"$(exec ls -ln /usr/bin/wc)" && echo "$size"` works with single fork and single exec, but it uses a temporary file for the here-string. It can be made portable by replacing the here-string with POSX-compliant [here-document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04). BTW note the `exec` in the subshell. Without that, Bash performs one fork for the subshell and another one for the command running inside. This is the case in the code you provide in this answer. too.

Comment: Forks should not be a problem; most people do not write an `exec` in a subshell that contains only one command. A temporary file is worse, but still, come on, this is just shell. Trying to limit the number of forks so strictly is definitely **premature optimization**, i.e. the root of all evil. Portability, readability and short length should beat small performance gains like this one. And if you need to optimize a working shell script, you should probably rewrite it (or at least its critical parts) to C.

Comment: The `-l` is superfluous in presence of `-n`. Quoting [POSIX `ls` manpage](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html): *`-n`: Turn on the `-l` (ell) option, but when writing the file's owner or group, write the file's numeric UID or GID rather than the user or group name, respectively. Disable the `-C`, `-m`, and `-x` options.*

Answer (score 10):

[BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution) systems have [`stat`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) with different options from the [GNU Core Utilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities) one, but with similar capabilities.

```
stat -f %z <file name>
```

This works on [macOS](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html) (tested on 10.12), [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stat&sektion=1), [NetBSD](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi/man?stat+1) and [OpenBSD](http://man.openbsd.org/stat.1).

Comment: Solaris does not have `stat` utility at all, though.

Comment: Busybox doesn't support that structure: stat: unrecognized option: %
BusyBox v1.32.1 () multi-call binary.

Answer (score 9):

When processing `ls -n` output, as an alternative to ill-portable shell arrays, you can use the positional arguments, which form the only array and are the only local variables in the standard shell. Wrap the overwrite of positional arguments in a function to preserve the original arguments to your script or function.

```
getsize() { set -- $(ls -dn "$1") && echo $5; }
getsize FILE
```

This splits the output of `ln -dn` according to current [`IFS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator) environment variable settings, assigns it to positional arguments and echoes the fifth one. The `-d` ensures directories are handled properly and the `-n` assures that user and group names do not need to be resolved, unlike with `-l`. Also, user and group names containing white space could theoretically break the expected line structure; they are usually disallowed, but this possibility still makes the programmer stop and think.

Answer (score 8):

Cross-platform fastest solution (it only uses a single fork() for **ls**, doesn't attempt to count actual characters, doesn't spawn unneeded awk, perl, etc.).

It was tested on Mac OS X and Linux. It may require minor modification for Solaris:

```
__ln=( $( ls -Lon "$1" ) )
__size=${__ln[3]}
echo "Size is: $__size bytes"
```

If required, simplify **ls** arguments, and adjust the offset in ${__ln[3]}.

Note: It will follow symbolic links.

Comment: Or put it in a shell script: ls -Lon "$1" | awk '{ print $4 }'

Comment: @Luciano I think you have totally missed the point of **not forking** and doing a task in **bash** rather than using bash to string a lot of unix commands together in an inefficient fashion.

Answer (score 5):

If you use `find` from GNU fileutils:

```
size=$( find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name filename -printf '%s' )
```

Unfortunately, other implementations of `find` usually don't support `-maxdepth`, nor `-printf`. This is the case for e.g. Solaris and macOS `find`.

Comment: FYI maxdepth is not needed. It could be rewritten as `size=$(test -f filename && find filename -printf '%s')`.

Comment: @Palec: The `-maxdepth` is intended to prevent `find` from being recursive (since the `stat` which the OP needs to replace is not). Your `find` command is missing a `-name` and the `test` command isn't necessary.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson `find` searches its parameters recursively for files matching given criteria. If the parameters are not directories, the recursion is… quite simple. Therefore I first test that `filename` is really an existing ordinary file, and then I print its size using `find` that has nowhere to recurse.

Comment: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name filename -printf '%s'` works only if the file is in the current directory, and it may still examine each file in the directory, which might be slow. Better use (even shorter!) `find filename -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%s'`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `find` command to get some set of files (here temporary files are extracted). Then you can use the `du` command to get the file size of each file in a human-readable form using the `-h` switch.

> `find $HOME -type f -name "*~" -exec du -h {} \;`

Output:

```
4.0K    /home/turing/Desktop/JavaExmp/TwoButtons.java~
4.0K    /home/turing/Desktop/JavaExmp/MyDrawPanel.java~
4.0K    /home/turing/Desktop/JavaExmp/Instream.java~
4.0K    /home/turing/Desktop/JavaExmp/RandomDemo.java~
4.0K    /home/turing/Desktop/JavaExmp/Buff.java~
4.0K    /home/turing/Desktop/JavaExmp/SimpleGui2.java~
```

Answer (score 2):

You first Perl example doesn't look unreasonable to me.

It's for reasons like this that I migrated from writing shell scripts (in Bash, sh, etc.) to writing all but the most trivial scripts in Perl. I found that I was having to launch Perl for particular requirements, and as I did that more and more, I realised that writing the scripts in Perl was probably a more powerful (in terms of the language and the wide array of libraries available via [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org)) and more efficient way to achieve what I wanted.

Note that other shell-scripting languages (e.g., [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) and [Ruby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29)) will no doubt have similar facilities, and you may want to evaluate these for your purposes. I only discuss Perl since that's the language I use and am familiar with.

Comment: Well, I do a lot of Perl writing myself, but sometimes the tool is chosen for me, not by me :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how portable GNU [Gawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK#Versions_and_implementations)'s `filefuncs` extension is. The basic syntax is

```
time gawk -e '@load "filefuncs"; BEGIN {
     fnL[1] = ARGV[ARGC-1];
     fts(fnL, FTS_PHYSICAL, arr); print "";

     for (fn0 in arr) {
         print arr[fn0]["path"] \
           " :: "arr[fn0]["stat"]["size"]; };

     print ""; }' genieMV_204583_1.mp4


genieMV_204583_1.mp4 :: 259105690
real    0m0.013s


ls -Aln genieMV_204583_1.mp4

----------  1 501  20  259105690 Jan 25 09:31
            genieMV_204583_1.mp4
```

That syntax allows checking multiple files at once. For a single file, it's

```
time gawk -e '@load "filefuncs"; BEGIN {
      stat(ARGV[ARGC-1], arr);
      printf("\n%s :: %s\n", arr["name"], \
           arr["size"]); }' genieMV_204583_1.mp4

   genieMV_204583_1.mp4 :: 259105690
   real    0m0.013s
```

It is hardly any incremental savings. But admittedly it is slightly slower than [`stat`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) straight up:

```
time stat -f '%z' genieMV_204583_1.mp4

259105690
real    0m0.006s (BSD-stat)


time gstat -c '%s' genieMV_204583_1.mp4

259105690
real    0m0.009s (GNU-stat)
```

And finally, a terse method of reading *every* single byte into an [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) array. This method works for binary files (front or back makes no diff):

```
time mawk2 'BEGIN { RS = FS = "^$";
     FILENAME = ARGV[ARGC-1]; getline;
     print "\n" FILENAME " :: "length"\n"; }' genieMV_204583_1.mp4

genieMV_204583_1.mp4 :: 259105690
real    0m0.270s


time mawk2 'BEGIN { RS = FS = "^$";
   } END { print "\n" FILENAME " :: " \
     length "\n"; }'  genieMV_204583_1.mp4

genieMV_204583_1.mp4 :: 259105690
real    0m0.269
```

But that's not the fastest way because you're storing it all in RAM. The normal AWK paradigm operates upon lines. The issue is that for binary files like [MP4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14) files, if they don't end exactly on `\n`, the summing of `length + NR` method would overcount by one. The code below is a form of catch-all by explicitly using the last 1-or-2-byte as the line-splitter `RS`.

I found that it's much faster with the *2-byte* method for **binaries**, and the *1-byte* method it's a typical **text file** that ends with newlines. With binaries, 1-byte one may end up row-splitting far too often and slowing it down.

But we're close to nitpicking here, since all it took `mawk2` to read in every single byte of that **1.83 GB** .txt file was *0.95 seconds*, so unless you're processing massive volumes, it's negligible.

Nonetheless, `stat` is still by far the fastest, as mentioned by others, since it's an OS filesystem call.

```
time mawk2 'BEGIN { FS = "^$";
    FILENAME = ARGV[ARGC-1];
    cmd = "tail -c 2 \""FILENAME"\"";
    cmd | getline XRS;
    close(cmd);

    RS = ( length(XRS) == 1 ) ? ORS : XRS ;

} { bytes += length } END {

    print FILENAME " :: "  bytes + NR * length(RS) }' genieMV_204583_1.mp4

        genieMV_204583_1.mp4 :: 259105690
        real    0m0.092s

        m23lyricsRTM_dict_15.txt :: 1961512986
        real    0m0.950s


ls -AlnFT "${m3t}" genieMV_204583_1.mp4

-rw-r--r--  1 501  20  1961512986 Mar 12 07:24:11 2021 m23lyricsRTM_dict_15.txt

-r--r--r--@ 1 501  20   259105690 Jan 25 09:31:43 2021 genieMV_204583_1.mp4
```

(The file permissions for MP4 was updated because the AWK method required it.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use **ls** for a better speed instead of **wc** which will read all the stream in a pipeline:

```
ls -l <filename> | cut -d ' ' -f5
```

- This is in plain bytes
- Use the flag **--b M** or **--b G** for the output in megabytes or gigabytes (per saying: *not portable by **@Andrew Henle** on the comments*).

BTW, if you're planning to go for: **du cut**

```
du -b <filename> | cut -f -1
```

- use -h for a better human reading

Or, by **du awk**

```
du -h <filename> | awk '{print $1}'
```

Or **stat**:

```
stat <filename> | grep Size: | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: *Use the flag `--b M` or `--b G` for the output in Megabytes or Gigabytes* Note, though, that neither of those are portable.  https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/ls.html

Comment: for macOS use  
  ```ls -l <filename> | cut -d " " -f8                                                   ```

Answer (score -3):

If you have Perl on your Solaris, then use it. Otherwise, *ls* with [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) is your next best bet, since you don't have [stat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) or your [find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix)) is not GNU find.

Answer (score -3):

There is a trick in Solaris I have used. If you ask for the size of more than one file, it returns just the total size with no names - so include an empty file like */dev/null* as the second file:

For example,

```
command fileyouwant /dev/null
```

I can't remember which size command this works for - [ls](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ls), [wc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wc), etc. - unfortunately I don't have a Solaris box to test it.

Answer (score -4):

On Linux you can use `du -h $FILE`. That may work on Solaris too.

Comment: Actually, units could be converted, but this shows disk usage instead of file data size ("apparent size").

Answer (score -7):

Try `du -ks | awk '{print $1*1024}'`. That might just work.

Comment: This shows disk usage instead of file data size ("apparent size").